# Append to a div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add content to a div every time a link is clicked. However, the added text dissapears immediately after being added. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <html>                                                                  
 <head>                                                                  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/files/jquery.js"></script>          
 <script type="text/javascript">                                         
     $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").click(function() {
      $("#questions").prepend("A question<br />"); 
      });   
});

</script>                                                               
</head>                                                                 
<body>                                                                  
 <a href="">Add</a>
   <p id = "questions"> </div>
   </body>                                                                 
   </html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `return false;` to your click-event, to prevent it from reloading the page.

Answer (score 5):

`<a href="#">Add</a>`

You need to have something in your "href", else it'll go navigate to the same page (at least for Firefox).

Comment: true, Firefox does that. 

IE navigates to the root of site / directory you are in.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with O.K.W

also putting return false;
or 
passing through a variable to represent the control on the function and performing preventDefault will stop the natural click event.

```
function(e){
e.preventDefault();
}
```